# Optimal setup for OSX PHP development environment: MAMP + Eclipse + Subclipse + XDebug? Other?

Tags: php, eclipse, macos, development-environment, mamp

I'm in the process of switching over to developing on a Mac (woohoo, new Macbook Air) after years of Windows. My previous PHP development setup was:

- WAMP
- NotePad++
- XDebug
- TortoiseSVN and WinMerge (linked to an Unfuddle svn account)

I've just installed MAMP Pro (evaluation copy of Pro), Eclipse for PHP Developers (Version: Helios Service Release 2, Build id: 20110218-0911), and Subclipse. I'm trying to get over the "new to Mac" hump at the same time as switching dev tools. Which is making me question my setup eleventy billion times more than usual. I've read lots of StackOverflow questions and answers, googled the heck out of dev environment tutorials. **What I really want to ask is "PLZ tell me what to do to get a good dev setup on my pretty new Mac!" but since that's probably not a very well-formed question, I'll try to narrow it down some.** (But if you get bored reading this question, and just want to point me to a good book or tutorial, FEEL FREE!)

MAMP: OK, I think I'm fine on this one, right? It's pretty much the defacto standard, if I don't want to hammer everything together myself from what came pre-installed on my mac. I'm probably fine with dropping $60 to get MAMP Pro, as developers I know have told me the long-term convenience is worth it.

IDE: I used Eclipse for several years... but for Java development in a Windows environment. Part of me is happy to get back to a full IDE after a few years of PHP in Notepad++. But do I want Eclipse for PHP? EclipsePDT? Something else? I picked the version I have based on several StackOverflow answers mentioning that EclipsePDT didn't necessarily play well with Mac.

SVN: I took the StackOverflow hive mind advice to install Sublipse for the eclipse integrated SVN plugin. Yay, it looks like it's working, or at least I can browse my repository.

Debugging: Zend Debug comes with MAMP, right? I've never used it, but I was only semi-happy with XDebug + Notepad++ on my Windows box, as it kept locking up and requiring a Notepad++ restart multiple times a day. Will I love Zend more? Should I stick to XDebug? (Or, wait, does Zend only work with Eclipse PDT?)

Now for the actual setup questions. Given that I've got existing Unfuddle SVN repositories, what's the best way to set up my dev environment? Put the source code into the MAMP htdocs directory, and point the eclipse workspace there? (recommended by many SO answers, IIUC) Vice versa, with code into the default eclipse workspace, and point MAMP to it? A separate Projects/myProject1 directory, pointing both MAMP and Eclipse there? I'm concerned that any of these options will work for the initial setup, but that I'll get deep into the work and discover that my debugger won't work for one configuration or another, or... I dunno, something I haven't thought of yet will cause a problem I could have avoided, *if only I'd known.*

Comment: Here's my setup: TextMate for all coding (you may prefer Coda) with Git for revision control. I use Filezilla for FTP and SFTP (although I've heard Transmit is pretty good). I installed Ubuntu on an old PC and use it as my test box for running sites and code (it's hardwired into my LAN).

Answer (score 1):

OSX (also the client version) already includes everything you need to develop with PHP! Oh, and it's all 64 bit :) (on Snow Leopard and Lion)

Apache 2 is included by default and can be enabled from System Preferences -> Sharing (its name is "Web Sharing", or something similar: I'm sorry but I use OSX in another language!).

PHP is installed by default too. You just need to enable it in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`: uncomment this line:

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

MySQL can be installed from binary packages, downloaded from: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/

The only things you need to change in the php.ini file (`/etc/php.ini`) are:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

You need to manually set the socket location for MySQL or it won't work with PHP.
Also, remember to set a value in `date.timezone`.

SVN and Git are installed automatically when you install the developer tools for Lion, which can be downloaded freely from http://developer.apple.com/mac (a free registration is required).

If you need Mercurial or if you aren't on Lion (so you don't have XCode 4), download the developer tools, then an application named `macports`, which provides ports for thousands common UNIX tools: http://www.macports.org/ . Once MacPorts is installed, you can install the required packages with a simple command:

```
sudo port install subversion
sudo port install git
sudo port install mercurial
```

I don't use any graphical tool for these SCM, so I can't really suggest you. I prefer the old, plain command line!

Developer Tools (the package with XCode) is required also if you want to use pecl to install custom extensions (the default distribution of PHP Apple ships doesn't contain some extensions like `mcrypt`, `gettext` and `intl`, just to name the three most important).

Speaking about editors... The one I really prefer and love is Coda. It's not free, but it's perfect if you want to develop in PHP: http://panic.com/coda/ .
It's also integrated with SVN (but we use Mercurial so I never used that option!).

For (S)FTP, I recommend you Cyberduck, which is free (open source): http://cyberduck.ch/ . Another really good client should be Transmit, but it's not fee (it's from Panic, the same company that produces Coda): I've never tried it (I'm really happy with Cyberduck!), but I heard thousands of good opinions about it.

Comment: Psst, if you use Coda, you already have Transmit. It's built into Coda and makes sFTP super easy if you want to edit and download/upload/publish all from the same UI.